# where query for spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google-apps api,  is there any way to find particular cell data with where condition

Example: I have one spread sheet, with column names are empno, fname, lname, emailid

Have to write a query like "**select emailid where empno='1111'**" .

here I am not using any datastore or any database , using simple spreadsheet only

I know that how to get particular cell data using following link

**http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#cellsQueryExample**

please can any one tell me how to get data with where condition like above

Thanks in advance
SKSK

Comment: The URL returns error 404 page not found.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve a set of rows (let's say 100) and iterate over them to find the one that matches your conditions.  If those don't match, try the next 100, and so on until you find the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this problem still exists or not, but anyway, I would do it like this:

=QUERY(A:D, "select D where A = '1111'",1)

This assumes that you have a header row: empno, fname, lname, emailid - corresponding to A,B,C,D respectively.

Hope it helped.